# Check before delete or just delete row?

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql

I have table `table_name` with `PK(id1 VARCHAR2(10), id2 NUMBER, id3 NUMBER)`

This table only grow ~ 1 million records each year.

The problem is that in procedure A, I must DELETE 1 row in `table_name` if exists.

Procedure A is run very frequently by many users. The number of actual deletes (delete an existing row) is very small compared to the number of times procedure A will try to delete a row.

So what is better **performance-wise**: just delete the row (solution 1) , or check if exists then delete it (solution 2)?

What about row lock for each solution? Will DELETE lock table row in transaction of proc A if row does not exists?

#### Solution 1

```
DELETE table_name 
WHERE id1 = p_id1
    AND id2 = p_id2
    AND id3 = p_id3;
```

#### Solution 2

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_check_exists
FROM table_name 
WHERE id1 = p_id1
    AND id2 = p_id2
    AND id3 = p_id3;

IF l_check_exists <> 0
THEN
    DELETE table_name 
    WHERE id1 = p_id1
        AND id2 = p_id2
        AND id3 = p_id3;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete the row.  To delete it, Oracle first has to find it, which is essentially the same as performing a select statement (but without returning data).  If Oracle doesn't find it, it won't delete it of course.  There is no scenario in which checking first yourself via a SELECT statement will be quicker.

Also, if a record does not exist, it cannot be locked either, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

1. Oracle cannot lock row if row does not exist. It just don't know how to do it :)
2. In worst scenario second solution is twice longer, but it try to success ratio is as small as you said, I guess, it would be equal performance in both cases.